# Can somebody explain to me the concept of mutability with respect to a NumPy array?

Tags: arrays, python

From the NumPy documentation:

> "NumPy arrays have a fixed size at creation, unlike Python lists (which can grow dynamically). Changing the size of an ndarray will create a new array and delete the original."

To my understanding, this would make the numpy array *immutable*, but from what I've seen, they're actually mutable.

When I was trying to learn about the concept of mutability/immutability, it was with respect to strings, and I was having a hard time understanding why a string was considered immutable if I could, in fact, quite easily manipulate it with, for example, a simple addition operation with another string. What I took away from that inquiry was that the key distinction was that you're not actually changing the original string. You're creating a new string that's stored in a new variable which lives in a new memory location. Ok, that made sense.

So how is that different from what NumPy is saying it does?

Answer (score 2):

Just because the *size* of the array is fixed doesn't mean it is immutable.  In an immutable array, both the size and the contents must be immutable.  With a Numpy array, you can change its contents (the values at each position) in place, without creating a new array.